# WPA2 Enterprise without a Client-End Certificate

Tags: authentication, wifi, radius, wpa2

This question is practically identical to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/155760/is-it-possible-to-use-wpa-enterprise-mode-without-having-to-use-or-issue-certifi), but the difference being that the authentication server is freeRADIUS on Ubuntu and the access-points are DD-WRT.

<s>Additionally, I would like to know if there is any risk to disabling TTLS (which from what I understand the part of the authentication process that requires the certificate) or if that is even an option.</s>

I understand now that there is a difference between TLS and TTLS. I want to use TTLS, since it does not require client configuration. I have assigned the answer to the post below because it helped come to this realization and I have edited the title to better reflect his conclusion.

Comment: You might want to update your question with the stipulation that you only want to eliminate certificate use between the clients and the RADIUS server - that seems to be doable within the WPA2 Enterprise spec, though I'm still trying to figure out how you'd implement that, exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skipping the marketing crap, "WPA2 Personal" uses the hash of a passphrase to secure the session key exchange and establish access to the wireless network. "WPA2 Enterprise" uses 802.1x EAP to secure the exchange. Technically the WiFi hardware could support any [EAP Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#Methods), but only EAP-TLS (Certificates) was required for the WiFi certification (it's been changed now, but was this way for a while), so it's commonly the only one well supported. PEAP, EAP-TTLS, and EAP-SIM are now also supported, though setting them up is mostly just as bad.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If 802.1X is actually what I desire and Eduroam uses 802.1X, can you tell me what I'm supposed to Google so that I can find a way to configure the dynamic acceptance of certificates as shown on [this webpage](http://ist.uwaterloo.ca/cs/wireless.html#toc-connecting-win-7)? You see, I was under the impression that certificates had to be configured on the user device prior to configuration, but if this dynamic configuration is an option, I would like to use it.

Comment: I understand now that what my link is pointing to is TLS and what I currently have configured on my DD-WRT router and RADIUS setup is TTLS. I will try and find out how to change my configuration.